# rbind create data.frame creating extra line every loop iteration

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a simulation data set for which I am trying to apply a for loop function too. The problem is that every other row of the output is a line of numeric 40's. If the code for simulation is necessary, ask. The data looks like this:

```
> head(dataforstack)
  time who   x  y beta theta sim
1 1900   1  50 50   50    40   1
2  200   2 150 50   50    40   1
3 1500   3 250 50   50    40   1
4 4000   4 350 50   50    40   1
5 4400   5 450 50   50    40   1
6 4900   6 550 50   50    40   1
```

The dput is this:

```
dataforstack<-structure(list(time = c(1900, 200, 1500, 4000, 4400, 4900, 5900, 
5300, 6400, 7900, 0, 700, 1900, 3800, 4200, 4400, 4700, 5200, 
5600, 7700, 1200, 500, 1600, 2000, 4100, 4400, 5000, 5200, 6300, 
6700, 2300, 700, 2700, 2200, 5000, 5600, 5900, 6300, 6500, 6800, 
1400, 2800, 2400, 3600, 5800, 5700, 6600, 6800, 7800, 7400, 3500, 
3600, 2700, 4900, 5400, 7400, 6700, 6900, 7000, 6900, 3900, 3300, 
3100, 5700, 6000, 7800, 7100, 7300, 7900, 8300, 4300, 3400, 3800, 
4000, 5600, 6500, 7000, 7300, 8000, 9200, 5700, 4200, 5100, 5000, 
6800, 5900, 6700, 7000, 8900, 11100, 5600, 5400, 4900, 5700, 
5800, 6900, 5900, 7400, 8800, 9200, 1100, 1600, 1400, 1900, 1800, 
1700, 2300, 2600, 3200, 3200, 500, 1100, 1200, 1500, 1400, 1800, 
2400, 2300, 2400, 2800, 400, 800, 1100, 1300, 1200, 1700, 2000, 
2200, 2500, 2600, 0, 500, 600, 900, 1400, 1800, 2000, 3000, 2400, 
2600, 1200, 1000, 1700, 1800, 1900, 1600, 1800, 2600, 3100, 3300, 
1900, 1300, 1600, 2000, 2200, 2000, 2200, 2700, 2600, 3600, 3000, 
1600, 1400, 1900, 2100, 2600, 2300, 2400, 2700, 3400, 3000, 2100, 
2000, 1700, 2000, 3000, 2800, 3000, 3100, 3800, 3600, 2300, 2200, 
2600, 2300, 2800, 3500, 3000, 3500, 3200, 3000, 2900, 2500, 2700, 
2800, 3200, 3000, 3700, 3300, 3500, 7500, 6700, 7300, 6700, 6700, 
6400, 6100, 6200, 7300, 7900, 7600, 6800, 5900, 6300, 6100, 6000, 
6700, 5900, 6100, 6500, 6400, 5700, 5600, 7600, 5900, 6400, 5600, 
5600, 5200, 7700, 6000, 6900, 5400, 5300, 5800, 5400, 6400, 4200, 
4900, 4100, 5700, 4900, 6200, 5000, 4700, 3200, 3600, 4100, 3900, 
4000, 4700, 4600, 5500, 4200, 3300, 3200, 2600, 2800, 3400, 5400, 
4900, 4200, 3600, 3200, 3000, 3100, 2100, 2700, 3200, 4400, 4400, 
4200, 3700, 4600, 2300, 1800, 2500, 1800, 4200, 4400, 4300, 5000, 
4300, 2500, 500, 700, 1700, 1200, 2700, 2700, 4600, 6200, 4500, 
2900, 0, 300, 800, 1500, 2900, 2900, 1600, 1300, 1400, 1800, 
2000, 1600, 1300, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1300, 1200, 1400, 1500, 1800, 
1400, 1200, 1200, 1100, 1000, 1900, 1600, 1400, 1100, 1400, 1200, 
1300, 1400, 1100, 800, 2600, 1600, 1200, 1300, 1000, 1100, 500, 
300, 800, 500, 1700, 1600, 1400, 1200, 1200, 900, 900, 400, 0, 
200, 2400, 2000, 1600, 1400, 1300, 1000, 900, 600, 700, 300, 
2300, 2000, 2200, 1500, 1200, 1000, 900, 400, 300, 400, 2600, 
2300, 1700, 2800, 1800, 2200, 800, 900, 1300, 1300, 2400, 2600, 
2100, 1800, 1400, 1200, 1100, 1500, 1500, 1000, 2500, 2700, 2300, 
2200, 1500, 1200, 2600, 1500, 1300, 1100, 8000, 7400, 7500, 7000, 
5400, 5200, 3800, 3700, 5500, 6900, 6700, 7600, 7500, 6600, 5500, 
6000, 5400, 3600, 3500, 5200, 6000, 5600, 6000, 6200, 5600, 5900, 
3200, 3700, 2800, 4500, 5200, 4600, 5700, 5100, 3800, 3700, 3200, 
3500, 3400, 1800, 5700, 5100, 4500, 4400, 3600, 1900, 2900, 2700, 
1600, 700, 5600, 5200, 3800, 3500, 3000, 2700, 1100, 1200, 800, 
0, 6400, 5700, 5600, 4800, 5000, 2000, 1300, 1500, 1000, 200, 
6400, 6200, 7100, 5600, 5700, 2400, 1400, 2400, 2000, 3000, 6600, 
7000, 8200, 5400, 3600, 2600, 3300, 3200, 3700, 3500, 6700, 9200, 
9600, 6800, 5200, 5100, 4200, 3700, 4000, 5400, 3000, 2600, 3200, 
2800, 2300, 2800, 2400, 3000, 3100, 3300, 2500, 2400, 2600, 2500, 
2200, 2600, 2500, 2600, 2900, 3300, 2100, 1800, 2100, 1900, 2100, 
2300, 2300, 2600, 2700, 2900, 1900, 1700, 2000, 1800, 2100, 2200, 
2200, 2400, 2600, 2600, 2000, 1800, 1500, 1900, 1400, 2200, 2300, 
1500, 2200, 2500, 2100, 2000, 1400, 1300, 1400, 1300, 1400, 1400, 
2200, 2500, 1700, 1700, 1600, 1000, 800, 0, 1200, 1500, 1200, 
2400, 1600, 1500, 1100, 900, 500, 200, 900, 1400, 1600, 1800, 
1600, 1400, 1300, 1100, 1000, 100, 1100, 2000, 1800, 2100, 1000, 
1200, 900, 1100, 1500, 1200, 1500, 1200, 1900, 2600), who = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 
94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 
47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 
60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 
73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 
86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 
99L, 100L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 
52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 
78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 
91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 
44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 
57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 
70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 
83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 
96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 
62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 
75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 
88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 
54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 
67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 
80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 
93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L), x = c(50, 150, 250, 
350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 
650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 
950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 
250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 
550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 
850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 
150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 
450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 
750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 
50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 
350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 
650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 
950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 
250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 
550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 
850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 
150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 
450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 
750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 
50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 
350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 
650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 
950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 
250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 
550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 
850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 
150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 
450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 
750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 
50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 
350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 
650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 
950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 
250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 
550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 
850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 
150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 
450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 
750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 
50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 
350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 
650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 
950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 
250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 
550, 650, 750, 850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 
850, 950, 50, 150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 650, 750, 850, 950), y = c(50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 
250, 250, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 450, 
450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 550, 550, 550, 550, 
550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 
650, 650, 650, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 
850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 950, 950, 950, 
950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 350, 350, 350, 
350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 
450, 450, 450, 450, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 
550, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 750, 750, 
750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 
850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 
950, 950, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 
250, 250, 250, 250, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 
350, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 550, 550, 
550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 
650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 
750, 750, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 950, 
950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 350, 
350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 450, 450, 450, 450, 
450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 
550, 550, 550, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 
750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 850, 850, 850, 
850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 
950, 950, 950, 950, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 250, 250, 250, 250, 
250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 
350, 350, 350, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 
550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 650, 650, 650, 
650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 
750, 750, 750, 750, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 
850, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 
250, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 350, 450, 450, 
450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 450, 550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 
550, 550, 550, 550, 550, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 650, 
650, 650, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 750, 850, 
850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 850, 950, 950, 950, 950, 
950, 950, 950, 950, 950, 950), beta = c(50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 
150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150), theta = c(40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40), sim = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -600L))
```

Here the for loop function:

```
res<-NULL 

detectionfunction<-function(data,sim,n,s){
  for (sim in unique(data$sim)){ ## looping over simulations
    ## we sample n hosts
    stti<-sample(1:n,1)
    infmax<-max(data$time)
    samp.time <- seq(from = stti, to = infmax, by = s) ## at sampling times with random start
 
    for (t in samp.time){##here you see that the hosts sampled is after the loop detecting
      ##time that hosts are detected as infected, thus changing every time you update the sampling
      test <- sample(data$who[data$sim==sim], n,replace=FALSE)
      
      ## get those hosts infection time
      inf.time <- data$time[test]
      
      ## if an infection time is anterior to the sampling time, we have a detection event
      m <- sum(inf.time <= t) ## we sum to know how many host are seen as infected
      ## we can also measure the true incidence at sampling time
      q <- mean(data$time<=t)
      ## and increment the result table in the loop
      res <- rbind(res, data.frame(sim, m, q, t=t, n,beta=head((data$beta[data$sim==sim]),n=1)),theta=head((data$theta[data$sim==sim]),n=1))
      print(paste0("sim number...",sim))
      if (m>=1){
        break
      }
    }
  }
return(res)
}
```

Here's the function in action:

```
res<-detectionfunction(dataforstack,dataforstack$sim,n=30,s=30)
```

Output has rows of the numeric 40. I want those rows removed. But furthermore, they are interfering with the intended output, so I need to figure out why my for loop function is doing this.

Comment: if you remove the `theta` assignment from your code, i.e. change it to `res <- rbind(res, data.frame(sim, m, q, t=t, n,beta=head((data$beta[data$sim==sim]),n=1)))` those lines are not produced. is the rest good for you?

Comment: This is not a sufficient answer, the theta column is required for future classification via a group_by() argument.

Comment: Is it possible to include theta? I assume so.

Comment: I think you need to give an example of the desired output. You are talking about `theta` column, but there is no such thing in the output of your function?

Comment: Fixed it by swapping beta and theta arguments.  ````res <- rbind(res, data.frame(sim, m, q, t=t, n,theta=head((data$theta[data$sim==sim]),n=1),beta=head((data$beta[data$sim==sim]),n=1)))```` I believe the bracket was misplaced in the beta arguement see ````beta=head((data$beta[data$sim==sim]),n=1))```` Many thanks